# A problem in Probability about independent, combined distribution

Tags: probability

$p$ is the probability of heads, $N$ ~ $Poisson(\lambda)$ and suppose we toss a coin $N$ times. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the number of heads and tails. Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

First I consider $P(X=x|N=n)$, and $P(N=n)$ to find out $P(X=x, N=n)$, and want to add all n to find out $P(X=x)$, so does $P(Y=y)$.

But I don't know how to do the summation...

Comment: I've edited my question.

Comment: And this question is following a question without $N$ ~ $Poisson(\lambda)$, but it is dependent, so where is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will help you with one step of your problem.
\begin{equation}
P(X=x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X=x|N=n)P(N=n) = \sum_{n=x}^{\infty}\binom{n}{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}  = \\
\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{x!}\sum_{n=x}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda/2)^n}{(n-x)!} = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{x!}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda/2)^{m+x}}{m!} = \frac{e^{-\lambda}(\lambda/2)^x}{x!}e^{\lambda/2} \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda/2)
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks, I will try to work out the others.

Comment: Your help is the key to the answer! Thanks, even there is a small step to substitute $(0.5)^{n}$ to $p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}$, but it is easy to deal with. A big thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience abbreviate $1-p$ by $q$

Working out the equality

$$P\left(X=k\right)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}P\left(X=k\mid N=k+m\right)P\left(N=k+m\right)$$
results in: $$P\left(X=k\right)=\frac{e^{-\lambda p}\left(\lambda p\right)^{k}}{k!}$$

And likewise it can be found that: $$P\left(Y=m\right)=\frac{e^{-\lambda q}\left(\lambda q\right)^{m}}{m!}$$

Equality:$$P\left(X=k\wedge Y=m\right)=P\left(X=k\mid N=k+m\right)P\left(N=k+m\right)$$
can be used to verify: $$P\left(X=k\wedge Y=m\right)=P\left(X=k\right)P\left(Y=m\right)$$

Comment: Thank you. But the process to get $P(Y=m), P(X=k)$ is the key part I want to ask, which is answered by @Marc, anyway, thank you :)